# Dynamic generatation of equation system for odeint

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I have a ODE system for `odeint` Python module:

```
def equations(p, t, lmbds):
    return np.array([-p[0] * lmbds[0] + p[1] * lmbds[1],
                     -p[1] * lmbds[1] - p[1] * lmbds[2] + p[0] * lmbds[0]])
```

This system corresponding to the Markov chain with two states three intensity.

The system of equations can contain a different number of equations. Is it possible to generate them on the go, depending on the number of equation entered by the user?

Comment: I bet it can, what is the rule for equation population ?

Comment: For each state we generate an equation in this way: `dp1/dt = - probability_of_being_in_current_state * outgoing_lambda + probability_of_adjacent_state * incoming_lambda `

Comment: Please see my answer, basically that logic shall be held in the `get_equation` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see approach of the creating n equations below:

```
def get_equation(p, t, lmbds, n):
    """ Returns equation for provided n. """
    # Create and return equation

def equations(p, t, lmbds, eq_num):
    equations = []
    for n in range(eq_num):
        equation = get_equation(p, t, lmbds, n)
        equations.append(equation)
    return np.array(*equations)
```

Comment: I'll check this way. Thanks!